# How to customize open with menu in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, finder, defaults, file-extensions

I want to customize the right click/"open with" menu for some file extensions like jpg, in order to see just the 4 apps i want to use with this file type. Google suggests me to edit the info.plist file of the apps (Applications/**/Contents/) by changing the CFBundleTypeExtensions section. This does not seem to work anymore in Yosemite. Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `LaunchServices` for changes to take effect:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain user;killall Finder
```

Comment: I have accidentally removed the whole <dict> part in order to delete a specific app from the open with menu. Now some apps do not just start, giving the error "quit unexpectedly". Do you somehow know how can i restore those info.plist files?